# Automatically numbering and referencing Sphinx tables

Tags: formatting, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to reference Sphinx tables the following way:

```
.. table Supertable

    +--------+----+
    |Foo     |Bar |
    +--------+----+
```

And then:

```
:table:`Supertable`
```

And magic! The problem is, that there are certain tables, that could be referenced throughout one document and such linking could come very useful.

On a side note the approach I've illustrated my question with doesn't work.

Also, as another part of the same question, is there a way to automatically numerate the tables? I'm pretty positive I've seen one somewhere, but it could be something manual. I mean like in:

*Table 11: Consumption of peanut butter by the state.*.

This functionality, if available at all, is eluding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've found an answer to the first part of my question. Actually it's a nobrainer:

```
.. _table:

.. table Supertable

    +--------+----+
    |Foo     |Bar |
    +--------+----+
```

And then:

```
:ref:`table`
```

As for enumerated tables I have actually seen enumerated figures, not tables and it gets done in LaTeX output. I looked around and haven't found any trace of automatically enumerated tables in Sphinx. It would probably make a good feature request, but for now there seems to be no such feature.

**PS**: I've checked and actually tables are also enumerated in LaTeX. There is also a related problem discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686310/referencing-figures-with-numbers-in-sphinx-and-restructuredtext) question.

Comment: I kinda touched on this a while ago in this post. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681236/csv-table-formatting-through-preamble/18519419#18519419](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681236/csv-table-formatting-through-preamble/18519419#18519419)

Comment: It requires extensions, which I'm personally trying to avoid, or at least fork it and make a portable version out of it to be distributed together with the project. But thanks. I'm gonna keep the link for future reference.